# "В первый раз" или "первый раз"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Как правильно употреблять эту фразу в предложениях, где она выступает в качестве ответа на вопрос "когда"?

Answer (score 3):

Хотелось бы всю фразу видеть. Или контекст.

Вообще говоря, грамматически предлог обычно не требуется, но допустим. 
А в выражениях типа "в последний раз", "на этот раз" и т. д. без него плохо стилистически.

Answer (score 3):

Я так понял, вы имеете в виду значение "впервые". Можно и так и так. Если посмотреть употребление "первого раза", то можно отметить, что сочетание уже долгое время используется и без предлога, и с предлогом, причём в последние десятилетия без предлога всё чаще и чаще.

Любопытно при этом, что ещё 100 лет назад вполне можно было сказать "в первый раз в жизни", что сейчас звучит уже более, чем несколько натянуто. Тогда же "в первый раз в жизни" и "первый раз в жизни" могло встретиться у одного автора.

Мне кажется, что это синонимичные варианты, и если в 19 веке преимущественно было с предлогом, то сейчас бывает и так и так, а в ряде сочетаний, например, "первый раз в жизни" с предлогом звучит странно. На мой слух, естественно. Важно, что "первый раз" в чистом виде в значении "впервые" встречался  и 200, и более лет назад. А вот "на первый раз" в 19 веке хоть и использовалось, сейчас утратило функции значения "впервые".

В каких-то сочетаниях предлог может проявляться: "как и в первый раз", уже упомянутый "на/в этот раз", "даже в первый раз", "только в первый раз" или "На первый раз прощаю".

Проявляется также в случае возможного двойного чтения начала предложения: "В первый раз всегда сложнее всего" (без предлога можно подумать, что "первый раз — самый сложный").

Когда считаются разы ("В первый раз никто не ответил. Я позвонил ещё"), мне кажется, с предлогом *несколько* лучше — это если вообще использовать такую конструкцию. Но понятно и без: просто в письменном виде для благозвучия я писал бы с предлогом.

*Источник — можете посмотреть в корпусе и проверить сами. Общая закономерность вырисовывается.*

Answer (score 0):

"В первый раз я влюбился в 4-ом классе". Как понимать эту фразу? Если "первый раз" в кавычках, то речь идёт о девочке, и тогда "в" необходим (впрочем, есть замена: "впервые"). Чаще "в" следует опускать:"Первый раз мы уже отыграли" (я заменил "тайм" из известной песни на "раз"). "Первый раз нам показалось, что он смеётся над нами". "Я пришёл к своим новым друзьям в первый раз" (т. е. впервые). Одним словом, если "в первый раз " = "впервые", то "в" сохраняется. А как вы считаете?

Answer (score 0):

Выражения "первый раз" и "в первый раз" отличаются грамматикой и оттенками смысла.

«Первый раз» – это (когда) впервые.

«В первый раз» – это «в который раз», направленный В. п. Речь идет о повторяющемся событии, на него  ставится своеобразная МЕТКА:  это случилось в первый раз тогда-то, это сейчас случается в первый раз, пусть это будет в  первый (и последний) раз.

Иногда для говорящего такие тонкости непринципиальны, и тогда предлог "В" опускается. Но бывают случаи, когда это важно, например: (1) Первый раз (впервые) я чувствовал себя счастливым (продолжения темы о "разах" нет). - В первый раз я чувствовал страх, но потом это ощущение прошло.

Обратим внимание на выражения «в этот раз, в тот раз, в другой раз», которые обычно используются с предлогом, так как  предполагается существование «ряда подобных случаев», например: "В другой раз поговорим".

Comment: Тем не менее, когда я стал искать в корпусе, увидел — ещё в XIX веке почти с маниакальным упорством все авторы использовали "в первый раз" вне зависимости от оттенка смысла. Лишь изредка без предлога (а в XVIII веке ещё и "на первый раз"). Сейчас, как это лично я воспринимаю, форма "первый раз" вполне нормальна, и её замена на "в первый раз" воспринимается просто как, что ли, более "акцентированный" (что иногда является *единственным* осмысленным вариантом из-за контекста). Вы чувствуете разницу иначе?

Comment: "Раз" - это существительное, в роли обстоятельства должно употребляться в косвенном падеже: в первый раз, до следующего раза, раз за разом. Может быть, "первый раз" - это вообще разговорная форма, которую раньше не употребляли, да и сейчас не следует её использовать в письменной речи?

Comment: "Раз" это далеко не только существительное, так что если не навязывать языку структуру, нет причин использовать слово только в  роли существительного (ведь это противоречит сложившемуся за века употреблению). В XX веке сочетание "первый раз" без предлога определённо вошло во все слои языка — или, вернее, стало гораздо чаще употребляться. Можно привести и такой контрпример: в обстоятельственном сочетании *"первый раз в жизни"* современный носитель языка уже не употребит предлог в начале, что статистикой тоже подтверждается — с конца XIX века употребимость варианта упала почти до нуля.

Comment: Я почему поиском занимаюсь — все мы люди ограниченные. Пассивный словарный запас, быть может, 50-100 тысяч слов, какое-то устойчивое произношение, какие-то речевые привычки. Я почти всю жизнь провёл в Москве или, по крайней мере, в радиусе 100 км, диалектов не знаю, не могу судить из своего опыта об употреблении в 1980-ых годах или о речи в Сибири. Но если просто по текстами видно, что в середине 19 века еще употреблялся один вариант, а в уже в конце 19, да и первой половине века 20-ого он резко упал в пользу другого, ранее более редкого,— видимо, взгляд носителей с тех пор изменился.

Comment: Слово "раз" - это еще и числительное, и союз. Существительное "раз" в форме И.п.  может быть сказуемым, например: "Это первый раз в моей жизни". Поэтому не стоит навязывать языку структуру, но задача грамматики - определить эту структуру.