# Как правильнее: "в третий раз" или "третий раз"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

***В*** третий раз повторяю или просто *третий раз повторяю?*

Comment: Вопрос уже обсуждался http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/В-первый-раз-или-первый-раз

Comment: Простите, не поискал хорошо!( И спасибо за ответ! ;)

Comment: Заменил бы «повторяю», например, на — говорю. Повторить = вторично сделать. Что такое — третий раз вторично сделать, сказать затруднительно, т.к. неясно от какого раза считать. Не говорят же: повторяю второй раз, или первый.

Comment: >> *Повторить = вторично сделать* Ну да... Повторять можно много-много раз.

Comment: @shampar: согласен! Но уже в вопросе таком старом хочется оставить как было. А  с "например" у Вас не присоединительная конструкция? С ней просто без запятой.

Comment: Давайте-ка оставим как было.

Answer (score 3):

Как отмечает Д. Э. Розенталь, при выборе вариантных беспредложных и предложных конструкций подобного типа учитывается различие в смысловых оттенках: предложные сочетания указывают на большую степень концентрации действия. Ср.: видеть в первый раз — видеть первый раз; охотиться летней порой — охотиться в летнюю пору и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо, Стася! А как понять "концентрацию действия"?

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **третий раз повторяю** (обозначение количества действий).

Сравнить: Команда проигрывает **третий раз** (количество действий). **В третий раз** она проиграла со счетом 0:1. Уже **третий раз** она проигрывает с одним и тем же счетом 0:1.

**Пояснение**

Здесь может быть разная семантика, в то же время не всегда ясно различаемая.

**Из словаря:**

РАЗ,  II. в зн. сущ. 1. (обычно со сл., обозначающими количество). **Указывает на кратность действия.** Несколько, много раз. Единственный раз попросил тебя. Не (один) раз говорил тебе (неоднократно). С одного раза понял (сразу). Встречаемся раз в неделю. Тысячу раз, бесконечное число раз слышал это (очень часто). Ни разу там не был (никогда). Запомни раз (и) навсегда (окончательно, решительно, бесповоротно). Семь раз отмерь, один раз отрежь (Посл.). 2. **Указывает место какого-л. действия, случая и т.п. в ряду других подобных,** бывших ранее, повторяющихся действий, случаев и т.п. Отложим разговор до следующего раза. Всякий раз. В другой раз. На первый раз прощается. На этот раз довольно. На сей раз поверим. В прошлый раз мы договорились обо всём.