# Правильная формулировка предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь

подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "в первый раз в первый класс" или "первый раз в первый класс"? Или оба варианта не нарушают правил?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***первый раз в первый класс***.

Это такое известное выражение с красивой рифмовкой, с повтором слова «первый».

А какое значение имеет это слово? Я  первый раз (впервые) иду в школу, я иду в первый класс. Да, в школу  только однажды можно "пойти первый раз" (начать учиться), второго раза не будет.  Это первый школьный день, а также "первый учебник и первый урок — так начинаются школьные годы".

**А в первый класс сколько раз можно пойти?** Тоже один раз? Но если вы скажете «в первый раз в первый класс»,  то можно подумать, что вы не исключаете  и второго раза, то есть «во второй раз в первый класс».

Похожие темы обсуждались на форуме, но каждый случай требует **индивидуального подхода**.

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/В-первый-раз-или-первый-раз](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/%D0%92-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)
[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423752/Как-правильнее-в-третий-раз-или-третий-раз](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423752/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)

Comment: Большое спасибо. Очень доходчиво))